# How are capital gains reported when one asset is traded for another?

Tags: united-states, foreign-exchange, capital-gains-tax, capital-gain

Two assets with values A:$10, B:$100.

1. Bank account starts with $10.
2. Buy 1 asset A for $10.
3. Trade 1 asset A for 1 asset B (great trade!)
4. Sell 1 asset B for $100.

Obviously the capital gain is $90, but the key here is how should it be recorded, and after which transaction would the gain be recognized?

Comment: You used the tag "foreign-exchange". Can you explain how the scenario you presented related to forex?

Comment: @BenMiller If you replace asset A with "Euro" and asset B with "British Pound", it becomes a forex triangle trade.

Comment: I've spent many hours trying to research this, and can't find any guidance.  Is the gain recorded with the closing of asset A or B?

Answer (score 3):

Generally you are not allowed to roll your cost basis from one transaction to the next. Therefore when you sell asset A to by asset B, you need value that exchange your natural currency. So if the value of the two assets at the time of the exchange was $50, then you have a $40 capital gain at the time of the exchange followed by a $50 when you sell B.

Comment: I never said anything about $50.  I specified that at the moment of the trade, asset A was publicly valued at 10, and asset B was valued at 100.  It was a great trade, so where do the gains from the 'great trade' get put?  Into capital lot A, or capital lot B?

Comment: The $50 was just an example. When the trade of A to B occurred you need to figure out what their value was at that point in time. For my example I assumed that the value of either was $50.